# JQuery ToFixed not working

Tags: jquery, tofixed

This is my script:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#btnCalculate').click(function () {
        var salaries = parseInt(jQuery('#txtEmployeeSalaries').val(), 10);
        var nationalInsurance = parseInt(jQuery('#txtENIC').val(), 10);
        var pensionCont = parseInt(jQuery('#txtEPC').val(), 10);
        var expenses = parseInt(jQuery('#txtAnyExpenses').val(), 10);
        var income = parseInt(jQuery('#txtIncome').val(), 10);

        var labourCost = (((salaries + nationalInsurance + pensionCont + expenses) / (income)) * 100);
        alert(labourCost);
        jQuery('#txtTotal').val(labourCost).toFixed(2);
    });
});
</script>
```

However in the Chrome Console it states:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toFixed'`

Anyone see anything obviously wrong with this?

Answer (score 7):

use `toFixed` this way - (*You are getting that error bcoz you are trying to use that method on jquery object*)

```
jQuery('#txtTotal').val(labourCost.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Would you know what the purpose of Radix is in the ParseInt sections?

Answer (score 3):

You're putting `toFixed()` in the wrong place. (`toFixed()` works on numbers, yet you've applied it to the jQuery object instead of the number in `labourCost`.)  Use:

```
jQuery('#txtTotal').val(labourCost.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Can you also tell me what the Radix is meant to do in PareInt?

Comment: @Subby its to avoid on older browser to parse to base 8 integer prefixed with a 0.

Comment: The radix is the second value you pass to `.parseInt()`, and it determines which numerical base you are using.  So, `.parseInt(number, 10)` will parse `number` into base-10 (decimal). It's always recommended you specify the radix in order to avoid confusion as to the base.

Comment: Ah ok. That makes perfect sense. Thank you both very much.